# Adding a Centered Title When Using titletoc package

Tags: table-of-contents, titles, titletoc

I am admittedly an extreme novice when using LaTeX. I can use it for math commands, but I  have never used it to typeset/format documents well before.

I have a pre-created Table of Contents document, utilizing the package titletoc.  Here is the set-up/header code for it:

```
\titlerunning{ICMI 25}
\authorrunning{Table of Contents}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{subsubsection}[2pt]{\addvspace{10pt}\bfseries\titlerule[0.5pt]\filright}{}{}{}[]
\titlecontents{section}[0pt]{\addvspace{5pt}\filright}{}{}{\dotfill\contentspage}[]
\titlecontents{subsection}[10pt]{\addvspace{1pt}\itshape\filright}{}{}{}[]
\newcommand{\tocSection}[1]{\contentsline{subsubsection}{#1\\*\titlerule[0.5pt]\vspace{-9pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}}{}{}\nopagebreak[4]}
\newcommand{\tocTitle}[2]{\contentsline{section}{#1}{#2}{}\nopagebreak[4]}
\newcommand{\tocAuthors}[1]{\contentsline{subsection}{#1}{}{}}
\begin{document}
```

I would simply like to add a title at the top that says "Table of Contents". However, every time I try, I knock out the running head. I've read through the documentation for titletoc and am still not sure how to accomplish this.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This depends on the document class in use: it maybe typed as an unumbered chapter, or an unnumbered section. In any case, if waht you obtain  is not what you want, you should use `titlesec`.

Comment: Thank you! Finally found documentation for the weird document class, and I figured it out.